# XCode Debugging - how to observe a certain object without breakpoint

Tags: xcode

Let's say there is some object I want to keep an eye on, meaning I want to know the current values of the member fields of this object while I use my app - can I do that somehow without having to set a breakpoint within some routine that has a reference to this object?

for Example, is it somehow possible breaking with the debugger in the moment the object is created, but then somehow keep an open view to this particular object within the debugger to see how variables change?

I know it's possible to set Watchpoints that will break whenever a variable changes, but that becomes very difficult to work with for variables that change very frequently - I'd rather have a live view of the objects content.

Hope the question is understandable.

Comment: write logs to console. you can write what ever you want and exam it when ever you want. Yeah debugging is hard I know...

Comment: is it possible to output to and display mutliple logging areas?

Answer (score 0):

Good thought. Its been a long time after the question asked.

Off course it it possible. You can use watchpoints in Xcode 5 onwards. Watchpoints will pause the program if the value is getting accessed.

You can set the watchpoints in two ways as given below.

(**1**) Use the following LLDB command

```
(lldb)  w s v self->_your_variable
```

(**2**) Select the left debugging pane. select the variable you want to watch, then select on option Watch "_your_variable".

Hope this will help you.